# Can haproxy log unknown headers?

Tags: logging, haproxy

I need to take a look at **all** the headers of certain requests. I've been reading the haproxy manual, I am able to use capture to log whatever header I KNOW is there.

But I would like to see ALL the headers, unknown to me, that the app receives. Is this possible with haproxy's logging options? Some sort of regexp or iteration method?

I am using haproxy 1.6

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use (in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg):

```
frontend my_frontend
  mode http
  option httplog
  http-request capture req.hdrs len 512
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft [[%hr]] %hs %{+Q}r"
```

**`req.hdrs`** - Returns the current request headers as string including the last empty line separating headers from the request body 
**`%hr`** - print captured request headers

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You log known headers with [**`capture request header`**](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4-capture%20request%20header) directive but HAproxy 1.6 introduces a new directive, the [**`http-request capture`**](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#http-request) syntax.

> **`http-request capture <sample> [ len <length> | id <id> ]`** :
>     captures sample expression `<sample>` from the request buffer, and converts
>     it to a string of at most `<len>` characters. The resulting string is
>     stored into the next request "capture" slot, so it will possibly appear
>     next to some captured HTTP headers. It will then automatically appear in
>     the logs, and it will be possible to extract it using sample fetch rules
>     to feed it into headers or anything. The length should be limited given
>     that this size will be allocated for each capture during the whole
>     session life. Please check section 7.3 (Fetching samples) and "capture
>     request header" for more information.

which I think you can configure to use regex expressions as `<sample>`